# Changing Digits Size For Main Font in Xelatex

Tags: xetex, fontsize

In Xelatex, I can change the size of digits in math mode using, for example

```
\setmathsfont(Digits)[Scale=0.9]{Bodoni}
```

Is there a similar procedure to do the same with the digits for the main font? I tried the obvious line (the analogous to the previous one, but using `setmainfont`) and it did not work.
Any help will be appreciated. And sorry if this was asked in another thread. I could not find it.
Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Maths digits are in the Mathematical Alphanumeric Symbols unicode block (hence: `unicode-math` package commands and options and thousands of symbols); text digits are in Basic Latin unicode block along with punctuation and letters, so "No (not yet)" to the question as asked.

But ...

---

... you can do:

Method (1)

You can define and then manually apply a font to the text digits.

Definition `\newfontfamily\fdigits{Noto Serif}[Scale=0.9,Colour=blue]` plus usage `abc{\fdigits 123}` gives:

[image: manual method]

MWE

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Noto Serif}
\newfontfamily\fdigits{Noto Serif}[Scale=0.9,Colour=blue]

\begin{document}

abc123

abc{\fdigits 123}

\end{document}
```

---

Method (2)

Automatically apply the scaled font.

With Xe(La)TeX, you can use its `interchartoks` ability:

[image: auto transition]

MWE

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Noto Serif}
\newfontfamily\fdigits{Noto Serif}[Scale=0.9,Colour=blue]
\newfontfamily\fdigitsu{Noto Serif}[Scale=0.9,Colour=red]

\XeTeXinterchartokenstate = 1
\newXeTeXintercharclass \mychardigits
\XeTeXcharclass `\0 \mychardigits
\XeTeXcharclass `\1 \mychardigits
\XeTeXcharclass `\2 \mychardigits
\XeTeXcharclass `\3 \mychardigits
\XeTeXcharclass `\4 \mychardigits
\XeTeXcharclass `\5 \mychardigits
\XeTeXcharclass `\6 \mychardigits
\XeTeXcharclass `\7 \mychardigits
\XeTeXcharclass `\8 \mychardigits
\XeTeXcharclass `\9 \mychardigits

% between " " and "digits":
\XeTeXinterchartoks 4095 \mychardigits = {\bgroup\fdigitsu}
\XeTeXinterchartoks \mychardigits 4095 = {\egroup}
% between <most chars> and "digits":
\XeTeXinterchartoks 0 \mychardigits = {\bgroup\fdigitsu}
\XeTeXinterchartoks \mychardigits 0 = {\egroup}


\begin{document}

abc123abc

abc{\fdigits 123}

xyz 456 xyz
\end{document}
```

---

Method (3) - A bit of .sty coding

In `ucharclasses.sty` package (make a copy first, save it locally, rename it perhaps), you can split BasicLatin unicode block into digits, letters, punctuation mini blocks; add the relevant Package Options; and then in your preamble define the transitions between blocks (or between blocks and word boundaries).